# Redis connection taking time to execute "mget " and "setex" commands in node,js & socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io

I m facing issues with redis in node.js. I am using **socket.io** with **redis** (without pub-sub model i.e single connection). My redis operations take lot of time to execute. Whenever my number of socket connections increases, time for redis commands increases exponentially. Sometime it went 10+ secs.
I am struggling hard with this issue and am new to node.js.

How I come to know that Redis is taking time. I applied console logs before calling and after calling redis `setex` method.

P.S. : we run the same test with python script and result is acceptable. I dont know why this problem persist for node.js.

Already tried: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-running-slowly-heres-what-you-can-do-about-it/

any help is appreciated guys!

**UPDATE**- Added the code snippet. I am trying to make a basic quiz app using socket.io. The flow is to fetch all questions from the DB and cache it in Redis. Then out of this entire question set, I am randomly picking 5 questions and setting it in Redis.

```js
function populateUserQuestion(uid, cacheKey, languageId, cDS, cQ, totalRounds, callback) {

     // First step is to get all questions from DB and then shuffle it for every user
    userQ = userQ.concat(randomShuffle(filteredQuestion, numberOfQuestion)

    // Shuffling and retrieving questions from DB doesn't take time

    // Below is the code for setting the above questions for every user in Redis, which is taking upto 5 seconds when number of concurrent connections is high 
    redis.setex(
        cacheKey, 1800,
        JSON.stringify(userQ), function (reply) {
        callback(userQ);
    });



}
```

Comment: Show your code please, and which lib you are using for redis?

Comment: i m using redis [https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis]

Comment: Its something in code 99%... Show it please, if you can show it as is.

Comment: yes, please provide, how you've implemented, or just provide  code which is taking time.

Comment: I have updated the question for more clarity.